# Keynesian model: large and small economies equilibrium

Tags: keynes

When a large economy adopts a contractionary fiscal policy, for example, and the exchange rates are mobile, there will be a devaluation in the local currency - but there will be no full return (of the IS curve) because there is a small economy that is a mirror image of the large economy. Its exchange rate will decline (appreciation) and the equilibrium will be somewhere in the middle (international interest rate parity will take place).

Today I came across a more complex question. The large economy threatens to impose tariffs, which causes future disposable income to fall in **both** economies.

In my opinion, even though the two economies "push" toward devaluation of their currency, the large economy determines the move, its currency is devalued (ie appreciation in the small economy) and the equilibrium point will be to the left of the starting point (again, not a full return of the IS curve).
Another solution that came to me is that after the curves in both economies have narrowed, the international interest rate drops, and the change is over. With no effect on international trade or exchange rates.

Thanks for the help